# Python equivalent to JavaScript function object

Tags: javascript, python

I would like to know if there is a `Python` equivalent to this `JavaScript` construct:

```
var myFunctions = {
    'greet': function(name){
        return "Hello, " + name;
    },

    'farewell': function(time){
        return "See you " + time;
    }
}
```

So I can call the functions this way:

```
let greetMarta = myFunctions['greet']("Marta");
```

Comment: All functions are first-class objects in Python. Are you asking about anonymous functions?

Comment: Yes you can put functions in a dictionary in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to define very simple functions like these inline; however they can only consist of one expression:

```py
    my_functions = {
        'greet': lambda name: "Hello {}".format(name),
        'farewell': lambda time: "See you {}".format(time)
    }
```

For anything more complicated you need to define a standalone function and then reference it in the dict:

```py
    def my_complex_function(param):
        ... logic ...
        return whatever

    my_functions = {
        'complex_func': my_complex_function,
        ...
    }
```

And in order to call the function you can do:

```py
my_functions['my_complex_function'](param)
```

Comment: Thanks. Show me how I would call it pls

Comment: Exactly the same as in JS: `my_functions['greet']('Victor')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def greet(name):
    return "Hello, " + name

def farewell(time):
    return "See you " + time

my_functions = 
{
    "greet": greet,
    "farewell": farewell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def greet(name):
    return "Hello, " + name;

def farewell(time):
    return "See you " + time;

my_dict = {'greet' : greet, 
           'farewell' : farewell}

greetMarta = my_dict['greet']("Marta");
```

use dictionary to get the functions and execute